# Стоит ли изучать Ruby или сразу начинать c Ruby on Rails

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! Дорогие друзья, стоит ли изучать Ruby или стоит сразу перейти к RoR, тяжело ли будет сразу начать с RoR?

Comment: Что мешает изучать параллельно и по мере необходимости переключаться? Даже для сравнения можно ещё какой то фреймворк начать использовать. Благо для развёртывания нынче нужно пару-тройку часов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Обычно соваться использовать фреймворк без хорошего знания языка -- плохая затея, но в случае с Rails всё немного иначе.

Дело в том, что в самом фреймворке очень часто используются DSL, и для их использования знание Ruby не сильно важно (лишь синтаксис).

По-моему мнению, можно сразу начинать изучать Ruby on Rails даже если нет твёрдых знаний Ruby. Хотя конечно без них не обойтись в реальной разработке.

Comment: Спасибо!Всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

RoR это фреймворк основанный на языке Ruby, как можно не зная основ языка использовать фреймворк. Это если кодить на jquery и говорить, что я знаю javascript. Суть одна, но разница существенная.

Comment: не согласен

Comment: Довольно сложно писать код на jQuery и при этом не знать JS. Если, конечно, не сайт-визитку для кота писать.

Comment: Для того чтобы писать на jQuery, нужно:

 * понимание css селекторов
 * понимание механизма событий
 * базовое владение js

больше ничего не надо

Answer (score 0):

Вы так ставите вопрос, как будто RoR исключает Ruby и наоборот. Если бы это было так, то зачем тогда начинать с Ruby?
Но это не так, Rails - это лишь один из фреймворков/библиотек для того же Ruby, которые не исключают использование ни друг друга, ни стандартной библиотеки языка Ruby.

Так называемые основы любого языка (куда, кстати, в контексте веба стоило бы относить не только синтаксис языка + стандартные типы вроде string, но и стандартные средства для работы с TCP и HTTP, на которых также основаны и фреймворки и многое другое) на самом деле ничем не отличаются от сторонних библиотек и фреймворков.
Нет никакого резона выделять их во что-то отдельное. Скажем, общая логика по работе с HTTP (которую к "основам" обычно почему-то не относят, видимо, этот подход пошел из тех времен, когда HTTP просто-напросто не было) - также важна, как и общая логика работы с массивами, строками, циклами, нет в ней ничего особого.
Так что всё нужно изучать по мере необходимости. Но если хотите глубоких знаний тех самых основ, то следует всё, что вы делаете с помощью фреймворка (обертки над стандартными средствами), пробовать делать также с помощью голых стандартных средств напрямую. Это всегда полезно.